# How to get first string after character Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get first string after a character.
Example is like

```
ABCDEF||GHJ||WERT
```

I need only

```
GHJ
```

I tried to use `REGEXP` but i couldnt do it.

Can anyone help me with please?

Thank you

Comment: Will it always be two vertical bars, like `||`, as separator?

Comment: Yes always there are 2 bars

Comment: What is after a character ? What is exact pattern your are looking for ?is it the second string after first occurence of || ?

Comment: Yes,it is  the second string after first occurence of ||

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat simpler:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('ABCDEF||GHJ||WERT', '\w+', 1, 2) result from dual;
                                                         ^
RES                                                      |
---                                               give me the 2nd "word"
GHJ

SQL>
```

which reads as: give me the 2nd word out of that string. Won't work properly if `GHJ` consists of several words (but that's not what your example suggests).

Answer (score 2):

Something like I interpret with a separator in place, In this case it is `||` or `|` example is with oracle database

```
-- pattern -- > [^] represents non-matching character and + for says one or more character followed by ||
-- 3rd parameter --> starting position
-- 4th parameter --> nth occurrence
WITH tbl(str) AS
 (SELECT 'ABCDEF||GHJ||WERT' str FROM dual)
SELECT regexp_substr(str
                    ,'[^||]+'
                    ,1
                    ,2) output
FROM   tbl;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most general solution is:

```
WITH tbl(str) AS (
      SELECT 'ABCDEF||GHJ||WERT' str FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ABC|DEF||GHJ||WERT' str FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ABClDEF||GHJ||WERT' str FROM dual 
    )
SELECT regexp_replace(str, '^.*\|\|(.*)\|\|.*', '\1')
FROM tbl;
```

Note that this works even if the individual elements contain punctuation or a single vertical bar -- which the other solutions do not.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4f13e57afe31266b5972ac386807095) is a comparison.

Presumably, the double vertical bar is being used for maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) function

```
select regexp_substr('ABCDEF||GHJ||WERT ', '\|{2}([^|]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) str
from dual;

STR
---
GHJ
```

Comment: It works! thank you very much. Can you explain why you used  ,1, 1, 'i', 1)? What does it mean? I couldnt get it

Comment: Those are optional parameters, in fact you can remove them :-)

Comment: But when I removed them , I got ||GHJ , with || character